# Filename Encryption (without illegal characters)

Tags: c#, encryption, filenames

I have an encryption function that encrypts strings to use as file names.
Problem is that a lot of the encrypted strings contain characters that arn't allowed in a filename in windows like / or \ ...

Is there some way I can encrypt the filenames (or atleast make them not directly readable by the user until they are decrypted by the program)?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like something hashing would be better at.  Do you understand the differences between encrypting and hashing?  Both are cryptographic operations, but one is reversible and the other is not.  By sacrificing reversibility you can drastically reduce the size of the output, while still benefiting from the hashing guarantee of unique outputs.

Comment: Are you sure you want to encrypt the filename and not the file contents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the file name has no value (if it does, I would add that data as file content), I would just use [Path.GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) and pass that around.

> [Path.GetRandomFileName] returns a cryptographically strong, random string that can be used as either a folder name or a file name.

Answer (score 4):

I would make the file names *meaningless*, but not *encrypted*. This will make your life much easier. I would then encrypt the *content* of the file.

To get a random name you can try

- [`Path.GetRandomFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx). It returns a name, but does not create a file.

  Sample output: **atqsfpoj.rsh**
- [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx). It creates a uniquely named, zero-byte file in a *%TEMP%* folder.

  Sample output: **C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp35AD.tmp**